# Sorting a list of randomly generated numbers

Tags: macros, sorting, random-numbers

This is a part two of a question I asked a few days ago and was answered rather spectacularly by user *egreg*, which you can find [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566508/using-an-alias-variable-as-an-input-for-a-newcommand).

I'm now looking to take part of the LaTeX provided to me, and change the command that generates a list of numbers. I'd like to take the generated list and sort them by ascending order. The code that I have so far to generate the list of numbers is here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\randomvalues}{m}
 {
  \int_rand:nn { -40 } { 40 }
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 - 1 } { , \:\int_rand:nn { -40 } { 40 } }
 }
 
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Currently, it will output a list m number of random and unique integers between -40 and 40, e.g. x = -2, 5, 0, -10, 30; for m=5. I want that list to look like x = -10, -2, 0, 5, 30.

Comment: I also wrote an answer to the mentioned question. With my answer the generated lists are sorted in ascending order. And they do not contain any element twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very first example in the documentation of `l3sort` shows how to sort a list of numbers in a comma-separated list:

> [image]

In the example above, a comma-separated list is sorted with `\clist_sort:Nn`.  The first argument is the variable to be sorted, and the second argument is the comparison code.

I adapted your code to first generate the *n* random numbers, then store them in a sequence, and then sort that sequence with `\seq_sort:Nn`, and finally use that sequence with `\seq_use:Nn`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__davidg_randint_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\randomvalues}{m}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nn {#1}
      { \seq_put_right:Nx \l__davidg_randint_seq { \int_rand:nn { -40 } { 40 } } }
    \seq_sort:Nn \l__davidg_randint_seq
      {
        \int_compare:nNnTF { ##1 } < { ##2 }
          { \sort_return_same: }
          { \sort_return_swapped: }
      }
    \seq_use:Nn \l__davidg_randint_seq { ,~ }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\randomvalues{5}

\medskip

\randomvalues{55}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: `xfp` doesn't seem to be used here. :-)

Comment: @frougon Oops. Thanks :-) (though I left `xparse` for older systems that don't preload yet)