# Working with multiple variables with expl3

Tags: macros, expl3

This is now part three of what will most likely be a several part questions, first of which was answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566508/using-an-alias-variable-as-an-input-for-a-newcommand/566721#566721), second of which was answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566991/sorting-a-list-of-randomly-generated-numbers/566993#566993). Now that I've begun to start using `expl3` more extensively in my document, I'd like to know how to work with multiple variables within a new document command. The example I'm working with, for instance, is trying to write an expression that will ultimately go under a square root radical. Given by:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\underradical}{}
 {
  % Attempting: Setting a value to correspond to || or nothing
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int_abs { \int_rand:nn { 1 } { 2 } }
  % if odd indicator, use |, else do nothing
  \int_if_odd:nTF \l_tmpa_int_abs { | } {}
  % the variable
  x
  % Attempting: Setting a variable to correspond to an x shift or not
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int_val { \int_rand:nn { 1 } { 2 } }
  % Attempting: Setting a variable to correspond to a left or right shift
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int_dir { \int_rand:nn { 1 } { 2 } }
  % a random sign
  \int_if_odd:nTF \l_tmpa_int_val {
                                    \int_if_odd:nTF \l_tmpa_int_dir { + } { - }
                                    } {}
  % the absolute value of the summand
  \int_if_odd:nTF \l_tmpa_int_val { \int_rand:nn { 1 } { 3 } }
  % if odd exponent use |, else do nothing
  \int_if_odd:nTF \l_tmpa_int_abs { | } {}
 }
 
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\underradical
\end{document}
```

Where there are three distinct variables being used here, `\l_tmpa_int_abs`, `\l_tmpa_int_val`, and `\l_tmpa_int_dir`. However, this does not yield a desired output it gives an output of 2x22, or 1x22, or any combination as such where each 2 also has an equal likelihood of being a 1. I thought I was implementing the naming scheme correctly based off page 3 and 4 of the [expl3 documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/expl3.pdf), but obviously this is unlikely as my output is not correct. I can at least, get one of the 2s or 1s to actually being printed as the desired symbol or number, but only if I change their variable to be `\l_tmpa_int`. Naturally, I cannot have all three variables declared this to work as the compiler won't know which one I'm referring to. I would like to know how to work with multiple variables within a given new document command to allow me to fix my issue.

Comment: Except for missing the declaration of the integer variables (`\int_new:N <var>`), it seems you are missing the false branch in the `\int_if_odd:nTF` below `the absolute value of the summand`

Comment: @David G. It appears that you have forgotten to accept the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three observations:

1. You have to declare all variables you are using with `\..._new:N` (In your case `\int_new:N`) or a similar function. (This isn't necessary with `\l_tmpa_int` because that one is predefined in expl3.)
2. The naming scheme has the type of the variable at the end and the name in the middle. So e.g. `\l_tmpa_int_abs` has type `int` and therefore could be better named `\l_underradical_abs_int`. (Where `underradical` could be any name identifying you module.) There is no reason to name your variables `tmpa` if they have a defined function. (`tmpa` stands for **t**e**mp**orary variable **A**, it's used to name prefedfined variables for temporary use if you don't want to declare "proper" names)
3. In

   ```
   \int_if_odd:nTF \l_tmpa_int_val { \int_rand:nn { 1 } { 3 } }
   ```

   the false block is missing. You can fix this by adding  `{}` (or some other code) at the end of the line or, if the block would be empty anyway, you can use `\int_if_odd:nT` instead. (For conditional macros ending with `TF` there are corresponding macros ending only with `T` or `F` for cases where the other branch should be empty.)

Applying all three points would result in

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_underradical_abs_int
\int_new:N \l_underradical_val_int
\int_new:N \l_underradical_dir_int
\NewDocumentCommand{\underradical}{}
 {
  % Attempting: Setting a value to correspond to || or nothing
  \int_set:Nn \l_underradical_abs_int { \int_rand:nn { 1 } { 2 } }
  % if odd indicator, use |, else do nothing. Yould use \int_if_odd:nT,
  % I left \int_if_odd:nTF to show that this works too
  \int_if_odd:nTF \l_underradical_abs_int { | } {}
  % the variable
  x
  % Attempting: Setting a variable to correspond to an x shift or not
  \int_set:Nn \l_underradical_val_int { \int_rand:nn { 1 } { 2 } }
  % Attempting: Setting a variable to correspond to a left or right shift
  \int_set:Nn \l_underradical_dir_int { \int_rand:nn { 1 } { 2 } }
  % a random sign
  \int_if_odd:nT \l_underradical_val_int {
    \int_if_odd:nTF \l_underradical_dir_int { + } { - }
  }
  % the absolute value of the summand
  \int_if_odd:nT \l_underradical_val_int { \int_rand:nn { 1 } { 3 } }
  % if odd exponent use |, else do nothing
  \int_if_odd:nT \l_underradical_abs_int { | }
 }
 
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\underradical
\end{document}
```